# Scraping using cherio and request in node to get yahoo finance info

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape stock information from yahoo finance using cheerio and request in node.

I found that the price has an attribute data-reactid and tried to get it using that but I get a function back not a string when I run it.

```
const request = require("request");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

request("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EIXIC?p=^IXIC",(err,res,html)=> 
{
if(err){console.log("Error");}
else{
    console.log(res.statusCode);
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
  var price = $("span[data-reactid='34']").text.toString();
   console.log(price);
}
});
```

Comment: Looks like react is loading that data from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.text()` instead of `.text`. `text` is a method of `cheerio` object.

`var price = $("span[data-reactid='34']").text().toString();`

Answer (score 0):

If you try rectifying the following line in your script, you should get the result.

```
var price = $("#quote-market-notice").parent().children('span').first().text();
```

Output at this moment:

```
8,164.00
```