# How to scrape Yahoo Finance with Cheerio in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, cheerio, yahoo-finance

I'm trying to pull a real time price from Yahoo Finance, based on [an old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55987896/scraping-using-cherio-and-request-in-node-to-get-yahoo-finance-info), and the latest price attribute (data-reactid="47") seen in Yahoo Finance.  But the following code doesn't extract the price data.   What am I missing?   I would appreciate any help.  Thank you!

```
function test() {
  const url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL?p=AAPL&.tsrc=fin-srch';
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { muteHttpExceptions: true }).getContentText();
  const $ = Cheerio.load(res);
  var price = $("span[data-reactid='47']").text().toString();
  console.log(price)
}
```

Comment: This should do it `var price = $("[data-test='qsp-price']").first().attr('value');`

Comment: @SIM, thanks a lot!  It’s working.  It’s well understood!

Comment: @SIM, I want to utilize your code to get a postMarket price.  But I see price = $("[data-field='postMarketPrice']").first().attr('value') shows just a fixed value, not agreeing to a realtime post market price value.  Its real time value is shown"xxx.xx" next <span class=....> ::before.  How can I get that value?  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize that its tag should be fin-streamer, not span.  Changing the tag name worked perfectly.

```
var price = $('fin-streamer[data-reactid="47"]').text().toString();
```